# Render WTForms form with a single method?

Tags: flask, rendering, wtforms

Even after working with WTForms for quite a while, I still do not know and can't find any hints anywhere whether there is a way to just render a form, something like (in jinja template):

```
{{ form.render() }}
```

which will produce

```
<form ...>
...
</form>
```

As is the case with some other form libraries. It is a big do-not-repeat yourself violation that I need to mention all form fields in the template in order to render. And what if the form is dynamic?

The question is, is it really the case or am I missing something very obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*am I missing something very obvious* Yes and no. Yes, because [WTForms supports iteration](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/forms.html#wtforms.form.Form.__iter__) so you can in templates iterate over all form fields and output them. No, because, firstly, this feature (sadly) is not quite well-documented, secondly, WTForms are designed around simplicity and being framework agnostic and having single `render()` method would limit that.

Comment: Interesting, that after sharing the question and reading your answer, I've found  a solution like: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/forms.html with `{{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}`. So probably WTForms can be wrapped with the desired layout after all.